# How to send a WebSocket message from an httpuv server in R without using message callback?

Tags: r, websocket, httpuv

I have set up a simple httpuv WebSocket server which can receive messages from a WebSocket client and echo them back upon receipt.

For example:

```
library(httpuv)

s <- startServer("0.0.0.0", 8080, 
                 list(
                   onWSOpen = function(ws) {
                     ws$onMessage(function(binary, message) {
                       ws$send(message)
                     })
                   })
)
```

Is it possible to send messages to that WebSocket client outside of the `ws$onMessage` callback?

As an example of how I'd imagine the syntax to be structured, I'd like to be able to call: `s$ws$send("Hello")` and have `Hello` be sent to the client, without requiring a client message/use of any callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I have since discovered this is possible using the super assignment operator in R:

```
library(httpuv)

w <- NULL
s <- startServer("0.0.0.0", 8080, 
                 list(
                   onWSOpen = function(ws) {
                     w <<- ws  # Now, the WebSocket object persists in the global environment

                     ws$onMessage(function(binary, message) {
                       ws$send(message)
                     })
                   })
)

# Wait for client to connect...

w$send("Hello")  # Send message to the client
```